# Error with Docs.Documents.batchUpdate() but the method throws the error after it completes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I posted recently looking for assistance but ran into a new error that I can't seem to fix.

`Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only`

The script is part of a Google Drive Workspace add-on. The user highlights the templates and fills in input on a card on the Drive homepage. Upon clicking apply, the script creates a copy of the template then runs this function to replace all the placeholders.

The code works how it should, replacing all placeholders in the file with data stored in an object for each document id provided. Here is the function that causes the error, it flags this line for the error

`let responses = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(requests);`

The function itself is here

```
function replaceText(copiedTemplateIds) {
  let requests = []
  copiedTemplateIds.forEach(id => {
    requests.push(id)
    for (let [field, data] of Object.entries(enteredInfo)) {
      let placeholder = "<<" + field + ">>"
      requests.push({
            "replaceAllText": {
              "replaceText": data,
              "containsText": {
                "text": placeholder,
                "matchCase": false
              },
            },
          },
      )
    }
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(requests))
  let responses = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(requests);
  console.log(responses.toString())
}
```

The parameter is an array of template ids. enteredInfo is an object with key:value pairs for the placeholder and user input to replace

I assume the problem is the format of my request but if so, why does it only fail after completing the batchupdate() method correctly?

I can't seem to find any information about this error on SO or Google searches.

I've tried changing the format of the requests, adding {request: {...}}, messing with the placement of the template ID in the array of requests, adding an object `{"id": id}` and applying replaceAllText to a single document. It always completes the replaceAllText but still gives the error.

If anyone has any ideas on how to rectify this, I would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that the arguments of `Docs.Documents.batchUpdate` are `resource: Docs_v1.Docs.V1.Schema.BatchUpdateDocumentRequest` and `documentId: string`. But, in your script, the argument is only `requests`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
- Although unfortunately, I cannot know your value of `copiedTemplateIds`, if `copiedTemplateIds` is `The parameter is an array of template ids.` and the Google Document IDs are included in `copiedTemplateIds`, unfortunately, in the current stage, multiple Document files cannot be used with one API call. In this case, it is required to use it in a loop.
- In your script, `enteredInfo` is not declared. Please be careful about this. In this modification, it supposes that the value of `enteredInfo` is like `var enteredInfo = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2",,, };`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function replaceText(copiedTemplateIds) {
  copiedTemplateIds.forEach(id => {
    const requests = [];
    for (let [field, data] of Object.entries(enteredInfo)) {
      let placeholder = "<<" + field + ">>";
      requests.push({
        "replaceAllText": {
          "replaceText": data,
          "containsText": {
            "text": placeholder,
            "matchCase": false
          },
        },
      });
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(requests));
    let responses = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, id);
    console.log(responses.toString());
    
    // Utilities.sleep(5000); // This might be required to be used.
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, `requests` is used for each document ID in `copiedTemplateIds`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: I can confirm you are correct in solving the error. Once I changed batchUpdate() to have just an object of requests and a string for the id, it worked. However, I'm still confused as to how my original script completed the task. BatchUpdate was successfully applying the data to every unique Google Document id in a single request, as intended, then flagging the error after. What's stopping us from using a try catch to ignore the error and apply multiple requests to multiple document ids?

Comment: @jip101 Thank you for replying From `I can confirm you are correct in solving the error. Once I changed batchUpdate() to have just an object of requests and a string for the id, it worked.`, I understood that your issue was resolved.

Comment: @jip101 About your aditional question of `However, I'm still confused as to how my original script completed the task. BatchUpdate was successfully applying the data to every unique Google Document id in a single request, as intended, then flagging the error after. What's stopping us from using a try catch to ignore the error and apply multiple requests to multiple document ids?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your additional question. But, I wouldl like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your additional question?

Comment: Never mind, it turns out I'm dumb and had an error in another function that made it look like it was completing the task. Everything is corrected. Thank you for the help in this post and everything you've done for the community!